# Adding legend to pie chart that is wrapped by ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, legend, pie-chart

I am quite new with R and require some support with using the pie function.

I need to return a ggplot so I have wrapped the pie function with this.
The output is a pie chart as expected, only problem is, I want to also have a legend next to it.

I need to return a ggplot but not able to combine this with the legend function. Could someone provide some guidance please

Answer (score 1):

It would be just as easy to do this as a standard ggplot, then you get the legend for free:

```r
library(ggplot2)

slices <- c(10, 12, 4, 5, 8)
countries <- c("US", "Japan", "UK", "Germany", "France")
pct    <- round(slices/sum(slices)*100)
lbls   <- paste(pct, "%", sep="") 
lbl_y  <- 100 - (c(13, 42.5, 62, 73.5, 90))
df     <- data.frame(slices, pct, lbls, countries = factor(countries, levels = countries))

ggplot(df, aes(x = 1, y = pct, fill = countries)) + 
  geom_col(position = "stack", orientation = "x") + 
  geom_text(aes(x = 1, y = lbl_y, label = lbls), col = "white") +
  scale_fill_discrete(breaks = countries) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y", direction = -1) + 
  theme_void()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-06-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#Data
data <- data.frame(slices = c(10, 12, 4, 5, 8),
                   countries = c("US", "Japan", "UK", "Germany", "France"),
                   stringsAsFactors = F)
#Create variable
data <- data %>% 
  mutate(per=slices/sum(slices)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(countries))
data$label <- scales::percent(data$per)
#Plot
ggplot(data=data)+
  geom_bar(aes(x="", y=per, fill=countries), stat="identity", width = 1)+
  coord_polar("y", start=0)+
  theme_void()+
  geom_text(aes(x=1, y = cumsum(per) - per/2, label=label))+
  ggtitle("pie chart example")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using ggplot2

```
library(tidyverse)
slices <- c(10, 12, 4, 5, 8)
pct <- round(slices/sum(slices)*100)
lbls <- paste(pct, "%", sep="") 
countries <- c("US", "Japan", "UK", "Germany", "France")

#convert your data to a data frame
df <- data.frame(slices, pct, countries)

#create a stacked bar plot
barPlot <- ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes(x = 1, y = pct, fill = countries)) +
geom_bar(position = 'fill', stat = 'identity')

#change to coordinates to polar
piePlot <- barPlot + 
  coord_polar("y", start = 0) +
  theme_void()+
  theme(legend.position = 'top')
piePlot
```

[image]